# How can you check every objects variable in a class in C#?

Tags: c#, class

```
public class Enemies
{
    public livingCondition { get; set; }

    public Enemies(char livingCondition)
    {
        this.livingCondition = livingCondition;
    }
}

Enemies Enemy00 = new Enemies('A');
Enemies Enemy01 = new Enemies('A');
Enemies Enemy02 = new Enemies('A');
```

These are some of the defined Objects/Enemies (they are all identical other than their names).

In this class for example if you want to check every Object for their livingCondition and if they are all dead ('D') the App closes, how can you do that?

I have tried turning the class into a list and using for loops to search for  `Enemies.livingCondition == 'A'` and that didn't work,

I'm new to C# so I don't have any other ideas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit/additional info: I am developing a game and what I was actually needing was living condition A or D and basically if all the enemies are dead the timer should stop, and i know that for arrays for example you can use loops to find out if the whole array only had one char for example, so i was wondering if something similar was possible for class objects.

Tldr: I need to check if all the objects I have all have the attribute .livingCondition = 'D'.

Comment: Can you show what you tried and what the problem with it was? At the moment, I'm not sure it's clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just added additional Info, if any more is needed ill add it too :)

Comment: The code only shows a class definition. There are no objects (or lists of objects) that can be compared. And the additional info seems to refer to a completly different class as well?

Comment: Sorry i noticed it was badly formulated...  just fixed it hope its better now

Comment: OT instead of using a char for the livingCondition, try an enum. Then you can have values like Alive and Dead

Comment: typo. `public livingCondition { get; set; }` is missing a type. Also properties should be capitalized in order to differentiate them from local variables and fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the enemies in a container, preferably a list:

```
public class Enemy
{
    public char LivingCondition { get; set; }

    public Enemy(char livingCondition)
    {
        LivingCondition = livingCondition;
    }
}

// in somewhere else
List<Enemy> enemies = new();
enemies.Add(new('A'));
enemies.Add(new('A'));
enemies.Add(new('A'));
enemies.Add(new('C'));
enemies.Add(new('B'));
```

Then you can query this list in a variety of ways using `System.Linq`. For example, if you want to get the enemies with `LivingCondition` equals to `A`:

```
var enemiesThatLive = enemies.Where(e => e.LivingCondition == 'A').ToList();
```

If you want to check if all the elements in a list satisfy a condition:

```
bool allDead = enemies.All(e => e.LivingCondition == 'D');
```

If you want to check if there is at least one element that is alive in the list:

```
bool atLeastOneAlive = enemies.Any(e => e.LivingCondition == 'A');
```